# Am I interpreting "Removal of Contingencies With Offer" clause properly?

Tags: contract-law, california, real-estate

[C.A.R. purchase agreement](https://www.car.org/-/media/CAR/Documents/Transaction-Center/PDF/Standard-Forms/December-2018/December-2018---Legal-Forms/RPA_12-18_LegalChange_Draft7.pdf?la=en&hash=D75479062DD702151385150ADB8CC10A2C897FCF) has following paragraph that has a checkbox next to it:

> C. REMOVAL OF CONTINGENCIES WITH OFFER: Buyer removes the
> contingencies specified in the attached Contingency Removal form
> (C.A.R. Form CR). If Buyer removes any contingency without an adequate
> understanding of the Property's condition or Buyer's ability to
> purchase, Buyer is acting against the advice of Broker.

If my understanding is correct then whenever that checkbox is marked then together with purchase agreement there **MUST** be a [Form CR](http://247relm.com/uploads/3/4/6/5/34658071/contingency_removal_1.pdf) that explicitly lists what kind of contingencies are removed **at the time of making offer**?

In other words if form CR attached to purchase agreement would have "ALL Buyer contingencies are removed EXCEPT ... Other [marked] home inspection contingency" then buyer could still get out of contract under inspection contingency?

Comment: The information you provide is very incomplete and would require us to speculate. We have no clue of the contingencies at issue, what the form looks like, whether the counterparty will find it acceptable for you to add your own list of removed contingencies, etc. It is in your best interest to ask [the draftsman] for a contract that is clear enough *to you*. And relying on the counterparty's "explanations" is too risky unless those explanations are incorporated/reflected in the contract itself.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Thanks updated my question with links to forms (in California these are standard forms created by California Association of Realtors). I hope that now the question has enough context to answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If my understanding is correct then whenever that checkbox is marked
> then together with purchase agreement there MUST be a Form CR that
> explicitly lists what kind of contingencies are removed at the time of
> making offer?
>
> In other words if form CR attached to purchase agreement would have
> "ALL Buyer contingencies are removed EXCEPT ... Other [marked] home
> inspection contingency" then buyer could still get out of contract
> under inspection contingency?

The form is suggested but it is possible for a lawyer to draft a form or document to use instead. Brokers stick to safe harbor forms to avoid the unauthorized practice of law.

A something other than a C.A.R. purchase agreement were used as a purchase and sale contract, the contingency might not be there in the first place.

It is also possible to remove a contingency before it expired by its own terms from failure to make a timely objection, via an amendment to the original purchase and sale contract.

But, in general, a contingency provides an out to the real estate contract from which an earnest money deposit is returnable, when a C.A.R. purchase agreement is used, unless to it is removed from the contract by Form CR or some other document executed by the parties.

Of course, it is easy to image that Form CR is filled out in an ambiguous way that leaves the question unclear.